# TypeError: Object of type Locator is not JSON serializable when enter date field in playwright

Tags: python, automation, pytest, playwright, playwright-python

[image]when i try to enter date DDMMYYYY into date field, im getting below error.

```
TypeError: Object of type Locator is not JSON serializable
```

Below code i have used.

```
searchBy_start_date_created_field = page.locator("#s_startcreateddate")  #locator

page.wait_for_selector(self.searchBy_start_date_created_field) #waiting for locator
searchBy_start_date_created_field.clear() #clear field
searchBy_start_date_created_field.clear().fill(datecreatedstart) #enter data into date field[![enter image description here][1]][1]
```

Answer (score 0):

The method `wait_for_selector` expects a selector string, not a Locator object. Since you already have a locator, you should use `locator.wait_for` to wait for the element. Here is what the updated code wikll look like:

```py
searchBy_start_date_created_field = page.locator("#s_startcreateddate")  # the locator

# Wait for the element to be ready
searchBy_start_date_created_field.wait_for()

# Clear the field and then fill it
searchBy_start_date_created_field.clear()  # clearing the field
searchBy_start_date_created_field.fill(datecreatedstart)  # filling the field with your date
```

Also, you dont need to call `clear()` twice. Once should be enough imo.

Comment: E       waiting for locator(xpath="#s_startcreateddate") to be visible



::::::::: Still getting the error